# How to fix: Exception thrown: write access violation. list.tail was 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++

I am using struct to create a node and a linked list. But I got an error about the tail of the linked list and I don't know why. The purpose of the task is to load the data in the "items.txt" into the linked list I created. But it seems that the error occurs in the tail of the linked list. But I don't know how to fix this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct item
{
    string itemId, title, type, loan, copy, fee, genre;
};

typedef struct item Item;

struct node
{
    Item data;
    node* next;
};

typedef struct node Node;

struct linkedList
{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
};

typedef struct linkedList list;

void createList(list& list)
{
    list.head = NULL;
    list.tail = NULL;
}

Node* createNode(item newData)
{
    Node* point = new Node;
    if (point == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed." << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    point->data = newData;
    point->next = NULL;
    return point;
}

void insertHead(list& list, Node* point)
{
    if (list.head == NULL)
    {
        list.head = list.tail = point;
    }
    else
    {
        point->next = list.head;
        list.head = point;
    }
}
void appenTail(list& list, Node* point)
{
    if (list.head == NULL)
    {
        list.head = point;
        list.tail = point;
    }
    else
    {
        list.tail->next = point;
        list.tail = point;
    }
}

void readFirstLine(ifstream& file, Item& item)
{
    getline(file, item.itemId, ',');
    getline(file, item.title, ',');
    getline(file, item.loan, ',');
    getline(file, item.copy, ',');
    getline(file, item.fee, ',');
    getline(file, item.genre, '\n');
}

void readAllFile(ifstream& file, list& list)
{
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        Item item;
        readFirstLine(file, item);
        Node* point = createNode(item);
        appenTail(list, point);
    }
}

void printLine(item item)
{
    cout << item.itemId << endl;
    cout << item.title << endl;
    cout << item.loan << endl;
    cout << item.copy << endl;
    cout << item.fee << endl;
    cout << item.genre << endl;
}
   
void printAll(list list)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (Node* point = list.head; point != NULL; point = point->next)
    {
        cout << "Item number " << count;
        printLine(point->data);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Item item;
    list list;
    ifstream file("items.txt", ios::in);
    string line;
    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "Error in opening file.";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    readAllFile(file, list);
    printAll(list);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem i got is in the line 70.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems like list.tail is `NULL`

Comment: I know, but there is no data in the beginning. I have to assign it NULL just like the head, right? Or do i have to delete it?

Comment: Fix it by setting your pointer.  Pretty sure 0xCCCCCCCC is an uninitialized pointer.  Yes, NULL would be a good thing to set it to if you don't have a valid node for it.

Comment: 1.it's better to use nullptr to initialize empty pointer

Comment: 2. you never allocated memory to list tail pointer

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't get it.

Comment: Even though you explicitly check for EOF on every iteration of the loop, you aren't checking for error with each `getline` call.  A spurious end-of-line char at the end of your file will insert a garbage Item into your list.  But I don't think that's your crashing issue.

Comment: When you see something orderly like the 0xCCCCCCCC your first thought should always be uninitialized memory.  Some systems deliberately fill memory with values like this as a hint that you're using uninitialized data.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you really

Comment: There are a lot of "[Secret Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values)" worth knowing, but in general any time you see a value in hex that is repetitive, close to an English word, or otherwise unlikely to be random gibberish and you don't recognize it as one of the patterns you are using, look the sucker up. The program's probably trying to tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

Your `list` is uninitialized when it's declared.  Hence, it's `head` and `tail` members point to garbage instead of NULL.

Your forgot to call your own `createList` function.  You could do that. Or...

Change this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Item item;
    list list;
```

To be this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Item item;
    list list = {};  // this will set head and tail to NULL
```

Comment: Or more succinctly `list list{};`